# Как сделать из консольного гуишное?

Tags: gui, java

Вот консольное:

```
public class time{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
System.out.println(format1.format(d));
int hours = new Date().getHours();
if (hours >= 23 && hours < 5) {
    System.out.println("Сейчас ночь");
}
```

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Comment: Я не очень дружу со Swing, я хочу взять переменную hours, но ее нельзя сделать публичной.

Comment: А какая конечная цель?

Comment: Просто чтобы писало на окне время суток и обычное время.

Comment: Как мне из main дать доступ к переменной в frame?

Comment: @Mostalk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса, который вы будете наследовать от JFrame, определите поле hours и setter для него (можно передать и в конструкторе).

Что-то такое:

```
MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(title);
frame.setHours(hours);
```

В крайнем случае ваш код можно поместить внутрь вашего Swing класса.

И там, где нужно, вызывайте:

```
if (hours >= 23 && hours < 5) {
    textField.setText("Сейчас ночь");
}
```

Comment: Как мне из main дать доступ к переменной в  frame?

Comment: @Mostalk убери весь код из метода main, и внеси его в другой нестатический метод. А в main оставь только создание JFrame и например настроек JFrame